# How to have a summarized data on the first page and the rest of the page is seperated per grouping in ssrs 2013?

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-grouping, page-break

I'm a newbie in SSRS.

My first objective is to seperate the display of each item per group.

I've done this by setting the my tablix row group properties in `PageBreak` -> `BreakLocation` to `Between`

In result, when I exporting report to Excel, I get sheets seperated per Item.

My next objective is to have a first sheet with consolidated data from the rest of the sheet

Current excel sheet format:
`[Team A],[Team B],[Team C]`

Expected result:
`[Overall Team],[Team A],[Team B],[Team C]`

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a **List**. Set the grouping for the list to =1 (this means "all" basically) - you can then create everything you want on your Overall Team sheet in that rectangle. Once you're done, add another row to the List, and create a new List inside the second row. Group the second list on your team's unique identifier - that will generate what you're getting now but **after** the first "overall" page.

Set page breaks on the rectangle for the first row of the first list and group then on the grouping of the second list to get them to split into new tabs. Protip: the **PageName** field in the Properties pane lets you define the name of the sheet when you export to Excel!

Comment: Thank you very much! Dan! :')